# Pandas: Multiline data schema to single line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big (huge) dataset that have the next schema:

```
dt | id | val_t | val
1  |  1 |     1 | 123
1  |  1 |     2 | 145
1  |  1 |     3 | 234
1  |  2 |     1 | 234
1  |  2 |     2 | 433
1  |  2 |     3 | 453
..................
N  |  X |     1 | 652
N  |  X |     2 | 543
N  |  X |     3 | 324
```

and for many reasons, one of them the to reduce the size, I want to transform it to the next schema:

```
dt | id | val_1 | val_2 | val_3
1  |  1 |   123 |  145  |  234
1  |  2 |   234 |  433  |  453
..................
N  |  X |   652 |  543  |  324
```

I tried grouping by ['dt', 'id'] and then iterating over each group to build the new rows but it is too slow. I'm not figuring out a way without iterating over every original row. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, the combination of [`df.pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html), [`df.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html), [`df.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df['temp'] = 'val_'
df['val_t'] = df.pop('temp') + df['val_t'].astype(str)
df = df.set_index(['dt', 'id', 'val_t']).unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
df = df.rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
  dt id  val_1  val_2  val_3
0  1  1    123    145    234
1  1  2    234    433    453
2  N  X    652    543    324
```

Comment: Your solution worked great. I'm wondering now if there are a recommended book/article that introduces this way of thinking (I mean, multidimensional transformations instead of process with iterations).

Comment: @Hamlett I suggest `Python for Data Analysis` book , Although there are plenty of great articles on the internet.